# Is there a way to study mechanics without having to rely on free body diagrams?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, soft-question, free-body-diagram

For example, consider a very simple situation often used as example in teaching: a horse pulling a stone through a rope attaching them. The analysis goes something like this:

1. There is a force exerted by the horse on the rope (due to muscular effort). Let's call it $F_h$.
2. By Newton's third law, there is a force of reaction on the horse, equal in intensity and opposite in sense. Let's call it $-F_h$
3. There is a force of friction, of the horse on the ground...

etc...

And there are something like eight or six forces considered in such a simple situation! Imagine in situations more complicated, there can be like one hundred forces to consider in the diagram... Of course one will lose track and make some confusion... Isn't there a way to analyze the motions without considering the individual forces on each body? (or something like this) I know it sounds vague, but it's that I'm just starting to study mechanics and it's getting very hard to understand things the way they are presented... Is there some book that avoids such free body diagrams?

Comment: Typically each body has only two or three forces acting on them. That is not an overwhelming amount. Free body diagrams make things simpler because they focus on each body separately.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of physics.

There are many answers to your question. First, I'll address your immediate concern:

1) You do not have to worry about the interaction force between the horse and the rope if you don't care about the tension in the rope. For instance, say the question was "How much force is the horse exerting on the ground if the force of friction on the rock is 60 N and the horse is moving at a constant acceleration". So, the character of the question might determine the complexity of your solution method.

However, more to the point:

2) Physics is *universal*, in the sense that with a simple framework (in this case, Newton's second law) we can solve a huge variety of problems. You can use Newton's second law to analyze the motion of a block on a ramp, a horse pulling a rock, and a rocketship traveling to Mars - that should impress you! The tradeoff for a single, simple framework for analyzing a wide variety of phenomena is that the implementation of that framework can be complex. Ok, we could have one theory which deals with horses and rocks, and a second theory which deals with rocketships, but with an infinite number of situations, we would end up with an infinite number of theories. Then we are simply engineers :-)

If you are looking for an alternative solution method:

3) If what you really dislike is "Newton's Second Law", at some point you will learn about energy conservation, which is another way to analyze the specific situation you are talking about. You can't get away from forces (we didn't decide to use forces to make it hard for you - it simply turns out that it works!), but using energy conservation is sometimes easier (or sometimes harder!), depending on the situation.

Finally:

4) If a text does not discuss free body diagrams and force, you are not learning physics.